# can we call an index as an users input using pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas

when called directly

```
data['four'].Utah
output - 11
the dataframe is given below

                one  two three four
Ohio           0    1   2     3
Colorado       4    5   6     7
Utah           8    9   10    11
New York      12    13  14    15
```

also this

```
try:
    a = input('Enter a Column you want : ')
    print(data[a].Ohio)
except:
    print("enter again")
output - 
Enter a Column you want : four
3
```

but when tried calling by user input, not getting proper output

```
try:
    b = input('Enter country name : ')
    a = input('Enter a Column you want : ')
    print(data[a].b)
except:
    print("-----------------------try again--------------------")

output- 
Enter country name : Ohio
Enter a Column you want : one
 -----------------------try again----------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `data[a].b`, you are accessing the member `b`, not the member with the name stored in the variable `b`. You need to do `data[a][b]`.